# RAM decision for laptop

Tags: memory, computer-building

These are my two options:

```
Option 1:
    Number of sticks: 1
    Number of RAM on each stick: 4GB
    MHz on each stick: 799 MHz

Option 2:
    Number of sticks: 2
    Number of RAM on each stick: 2GB, 4GB
    MHz on each stick:799 MHz, 666 MHz
```

My laptop will only hold 6GB of RAM, so out of those two which is the better option? BTW my laptop supports dual channel.

Comment: It sounds like an old laptop and I recommend buying a new one, haha. By the sounds of it, it supports only DDR2 ram which is going to cost you around 120 dollars for 3 ram sticks. But to answer your question, most laptops only have two slots for ram, have you made sure it has 3 slots? Also, it is not recommended to have different speeds of ram since it will cap your speed unless your laptop supports dual channels. I would go with the first option.

Comment: No its brand new. When I bought it, it came with option 1. So is it better to upgrade to option 2 for 2 extra gigs of ram, but less mhz? @Tech1337

Comment: And I messed up, I updates option 1 and 2. @Tech1337

Comment: @user315388 you can't find any 4GB sticks at 800 MHz?

Comment: Also I'm confused - why not keep the 1 stick of 4GB RAM and get a second 2GB stick?

Comment: Just for my situation now, which is better?

Comment: I already have a second 2gb stick, just it runs at a slower mhz speed. @nhinkle

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a new laptop? Either way, I would go with the first option since it would be running at a higher speed and after 4 GB of ram it doesn't really help that much. If you need that extra RAM (ex. if you run a lot of high-end programs simultaneously) then the second option is fine but as I pointed out in the comments it will decrease the speed. It just depends on what you want to do. For normal operations such as browsing and running MS office software, and Photoshop, 4gb of ram is fine.